# PEGA Axis error: Parser already accessed

Tags: web-services, utf-8, apache-axis, double-byte, pega

We have a PEGA frontend, from where we are keying in double byte characters like Japanese and being send to distributed java webservice through axis. This is working fine when we send singlebyte characters. Only failing while using double byte characters. The encoding used is UTF-8 in the xml which is being passed. Double byte characters are being properly rendered in PEGA front end. Even the PEGA logs shows characters intact.

Axis version: 2

PEGA gets the response while invoking webservice...

Error:problem accessing the parser. Parser already accessed!

Did various combination testing and found the following...

single byte- working
chinese - working

japanese
Hiragana - working
katakana - working
kanji - not working

For kanji, PEGA is not even hitting the distributed code, it fails with parser error "problem accessing the parser. Parser already accessed!

Any pointers would be helpful...

Comment: Have you used the Tracer in order to find the step that gives you the error?

Comment: Yes. Pega throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

PEGA have issue with parsing of chinese,japanees, and other asian characters which take two byte storage and they have HFIX, for the following in many version and as of what I know they were fixing this issue in 7.2.2 version.
I would say raise defect to them to get the HFIX for your PEGA version.